# Mysql Query to count common number in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main table as first image and I need to produce output as second table. Can any one please help me to do mysql query.

Main Table

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select anumber,
       sum(tsp = 'aplace') as aplace,
       sum(tsp = 'bplace') as bplace,
       sum(tsp = 'cplace') as cplace
from table t
group by anumber;
```

Comment: Thanks @yogesh-sharma, Assume that `tsp` has n number of names, above query works well for fixed `tsp`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `CASE WHEN`

```
   select anumber,
           sum(case when tsp = 'aplace' then 1 else 0 end) as aplace,
           sum(case when tsp = 'bplace' then 1 else 0 end) as bplace,
           sum(case when tsp = 'cplace' then 1 else 0 end) as cplace,
    from table t
    group by anumber;
```

Comment: Assume that tsp has n number of names, above query works well for fixed tsp